# Android License Test Response - Never works

Tags: java, android, android-lvl

I've been working on an Android App that has already been published to Google Play.  For the next update (versionCode = 3) my client wants to include the LVL licensing scheme.

The first thing I did was set up a static test response from the licensing server.  I set the test response to **LICENSED**.  After reading this in the documentation:

> This License Test Response will be sent to devices using [my email address]
>   or the Test Accounts listed above for applications you have uploaded to Google Play. >Additionally, this account (but not the Test Accounts) will receive this response for >applications that have not yet been uploaded to Google Play.

I thought, not a problem, since my developer account email is the same as my Google Play account email on my testing devices.  So I should receive the test response when debugging the App.

After that, I read through all the other licensing documentation and sample code and integrated it into the App.  I used a **ServerManagedPolicy** with the correct base64 public key and 20 random generated bytes as the salt.

Once everything looked good I uploaded it to the device to test it, but instead of receiving the **LICENSED** response that I expected, I am *always* receiving a **NOT_LICENSED** response.  I went back and made sure that:

1. I was connected to the internet.
2. I was signed in to my developer account on Google Play.
3. The LicenseChecker was using the correct public key.
4. Clearing my Google Play cache.

At first, I thought maybe it had something to do with the caching, so I tried using a **StrictPolicy** instead.  Same response.  Since I haven't purchased the App from the store, I'm under the impression that the licensing server is *responding normally instead of sending the static test response*.  Here are some other things I have tried:

1. Waiting 24 hours and trying again.
2. Tried building the App with the android debug key, as well as the current distribution key.
3. Setting up and using a different test user account on Google Play.  I made sure to add this email account to the 'Test accounts' section in the developer console.
4. Uploading the APK to Google Play, but not publishing it.
5. Incrementing the versionCode from 2 to 3.  *This is interesting, because instead of responding **NOT_LICENSED** it returns the 'application error code' **ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED***.

This leads me to believe that the license server is always responding normally, instead of sending the static test response I set up to my developer account.  I have a feeling it may be because the App is already published, but I cannot risk publishing a debug build just to test wether or not it is working.

Has anyone been in this situation before?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, you need build and upload the new apk with version incremented **after** incrementing the versionCode from 2 to 3, this will solve ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED error. More details about ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377325/how-do-you-deal-with-licensecheckercallback-error-not-market-managed-error-code/10377653#10377653). Second, You may need clear cache in stock Google Play on the phone (Settings -> Applications), as it is usually cache the license data for some period.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have already tried clearing the cache (even the 'delete all data' option). I can't publish the app until I've tested the licensing code, so uploading it doesn't matter. It says in the documentation that the server will send back an ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED error if the versionCode is higher than the currently published versionCode.  This is my dilemma, I can't publish the app until I test the licensing code, and the **licensing server is not sending the static test response code that I set in the developer console**. I test with versionCode=2 and I get NOT_LICENSED.

Comment: If this is the first version with LVL integrated. You **must** upload (Note that Upload != Publish) the apk with incremented version code into Developer Console. The complete procedure: implement LVL -> increment version code/name -> build apk with release key -> upload apk into developer console, and from here, you can do licensing test before hitting the Publish button to actually publish you new apk version.

Comment: You shouldn't upload two apk with the same version code into Developer console, especially when there are code changes (says implementing LVL) between them, this confuses the Developer Console which one has the LVL implemented when trying to serve the license test request.

Comment: I've tried this and it still gives me an  ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED error.  I've uploaded the app and saved it, with the new versionCode and everything, but it is still not returning the test response code that I set in the console.  Note that the APK with versionCode = 2 is active and published.  I can't unpublish the app while I test this code.

Comment: You don't need unpublish anything for testing newly uploaded APK. Make sure the one installed on the actual device is the same apk (LVL with incremented version code) you uploaded.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, no solutions have worked for me either so far!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent hours and even days with the same problem, it is documented here and elsewhere, that pre-published license test is hit and miss, and more miss than hit from what I discovered.

The only way I've found to make it work "more reliably" (but still not totally reliable) is to have a hardware device that is a reset to factory defaults, then set it's PRIMARY google user as the same one as your dev account that has the app uploaded to test with.

The special AVDs are also not very reliable.

Comment: Yea, I don't think I'm going to get any further with this problem unfortunately.  My device was already set up with my developer account as the primary Google Play user.  Thanks.

Comment: @logray Setting only one testing account that is registered in your google play works fine. We there are more than one accounts configured in your device then the static response will not work. Than you for the great suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but was able to resolve it. Here are the things I did to fix:
1) on my device, I removed all google accounts except the test account I had configured for. Apparently, play store was still trying to use a non testing account.

2) I had to activate test status for my developer account even though I'm the main developer and only tester.

the version increment thing did not help and honestly was a distraction.....

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when testing using LVL library. I always get the 561 (0x231 NOT_LICENSED) response no matter what I set the License Test Response to in the settings page.

My paid app users don't seem to complain so I'm assuming LVL is working for them.

At first one of my apps had this problem and it went away after 1 day (published Dec 30 2012), now I get valid test response in that app.

However, I still get the 561 (0x231 NOT_LICENSED) response for a newer app (published Jan 31 2013)

So now I just comment out (disable the alert dialog code that pops up for 561) after I publish the APK and continue my development for the next release.

I un-comment (enable the alert dialog code) before I publish again!

I contacted Google Play, they referred me to their developer forums. I posted the same question there but then I can't find my post.

Good to know that I'm not the only one facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I am adding anything new but having similar problems and frustrations at what-should-be-happening vs what-is-happening I'll offer up this which seemed to work: 1) remove all of the users in the Play Console's license testing list of users; 2) whatever device you are testing remove all of the Google accounts; 3) on that same device create a new, unique Google account (e.g., iamalicensetester@gmail.com); 4) add that Google account to the Play Console license testing list of users.

What I think might be happening is that if you have more than one account on a device and one of them is licensed then a non-licensed account of that same device (or other devices) will inherit that characteristic. This idea of mine is just a model (all models are wrong, but some are useful) to (mostly) allow me to get back to the work of testing...and (partially) to have some way to explain this nonsense to myself.

I did try most of the things mentioned above...clearing the cache, the storage, etc. -- you'd think that Google would want a better facility with dashboarding but don't know if that is even on their radar. I mean, revenue, right?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem and I am giving here some advices that can help you to solve it:

1. Clearing Google Play cache -> **doesn't matter**
2. Take care of your app's **signing keys**:

- If you upload you app to Play store you must sign it with a key - ensure this is the same key that the app you're debugging is signed also

3. In Play console there are 2 places you can configure test responses - "**Test licenses**" section for all apps and "**App integrity**" section under app specific page. My experiments lead me to conclusion that "App integrity" settings **have higher priority over general settings for all apps** and even more: general settings just don't work. Setting it to licensed/not licensed always return not licensed if integrity test weren't set. However if they existed, response followed them (not those from general section)

Note: App integrity settings come from Integrity Developer API that has to be turn on