# Android License Verification Check returns always Error Code 6

Tags: java, android, android-lvl

My LicenseCheckerCallback calls method applicationError and return errorCode 6.
In my LogCat I get the following JavaStack:

```
02-27 08:55:18.258: I/LicenseChecker(19572): Binding to licensing service.
02-27 08:55:18.268: D/dalvikvm(19572): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-27 08:55:18.268: D/dalvikvm(19572): GC_CONCURRENT freed 112K, 12% free 7284K/8263K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 27ms
02-27 08:55:28.233: I/System.out(19728): broadcast Received
02-27 08:55:29.408: I/System.out(19572): DIALOG_RETRY Error
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572): Activity My_company.My_appname.LicenseVerification has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker@41da7698 that was originally bound here
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity My_company.My_appname.LicenseVerification has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker@41da7698 that was originally bound here
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:966)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:860)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1364)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1356)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:401)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker.checkAccess(LicenseChecker.java:150)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at My_company.My_appname.LicenseVerification.bCheckLicense(LicenseVerification.java:84)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at My_company.My_appname.LicenseVerification.onCreate(LicenseVerification.java:65)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-27 08:55:29.603: E/ActivityThread(19572):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

- My License Verification Implementation :

  ```
  public class LicenseVerification  extends Activity {

  private static final int LICENSED = 0x0;
  private static final int NOT_LICENSED = 0x1;
  private static final int LICENSED_OLD_KEY = 0x2;
  private static final int ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED = 0x3;
  private static final int ERROR_SERVER_FAILURE = 0x4;
  private static final int ERROR_OVER_QUOTA = 0x5;

  private static final int ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER = 0x101;
  private static final int ERROR_INVALID_PACKAGE_NAME = 0x102;
  private static final int ERROR_NON_MATCHING_UID = 0x103;

  ApplicationContextProvider application;

   private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] {
          -46, 65, 37, -128, -103, -57, 74, -64, 51, 88, -91, -45, 77, -17, -36, -113, -11, 32, -64,
          89
      };

   private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;
   private LicenseChecker mChecker;
   private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "MYKEY";

   public void sendBackLicenseCheck(String sStatus, int errorCode){
          Intent replyIntent = new Intent("My_company.My_app.A_CUSTOM_INTENT");
          replyIntent.putExtra("Status", sStatus);
          replyIntent.putExtra("ErrorCode", errorCode);
          this.sendBroadcast(replyIntent);
   }
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          Toast.makeText(this, "LicenseVerification ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          CheckLicense();
          finish();
   }
   public void CheckLicense(){
          Context AppContext=application.getContext();
          String sPackageName=AppContext.getPackageName();
          //Toast.makeText(this, "sPackageName: "+sPackageName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback2();
          String deviceId = Secure.getString(AppContext.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
          mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, new ServerManagedPolicy(AppContext, new AESObfuscator(SALT, sPackageName, deviceId)),BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
          mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
   }
   private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback2 implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
          public void allow(int reason) {
              System.out.println("Allow");
              sendBackLicenseCheck("Allow",-1);
          }
          public void dontAllow(int reason) {

              sendBackLicenseCheck("Deny",0);
              System.out.println("DIALOG_GOTOMARKET");

              if (reason == Policy.RETRY) {
                  System.out.println("DIALOG_RETRY");
              } else {
                  System.out.println("DIALOG_GOTOMARKET");
              }
          }
          @Override
          public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
              sendBackLicenseCheck("Error",errorCode);
              System.out.println("DIALOG_RETRY Error");
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- I have published the app in the BETA TEST Phase and fetched the BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY for my code.
- I have added a licensetest-account in the settings in the developer console under LICENSETEST
- I set the Testreponse to LICENCED

Now when I debug the application locally on my pc using eclipse I see that my LicenseCheckerCallback (MyLicenseCheckerCallback2) calls applicationError with ErrorCode 6. I did not found any information about Code 6 and I have no clue what could be the reason.

Any hints ?

Comment: Does your app have the CHECK_LICENSE permission?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was it. I am stupid, because I guess its one of the first steps in the Google Guide. Now I get an errorcode 3. So the question is answered with : ErrorCode 6 means no permissions to check license. Thank you. Any guess about the errorcode 3 ?

Comment: For ErrorCode 3 exists already a thread. I will check this out. Thanks a lot to all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377325/how-do-you-deal-with-licensecheckercallback-error-not-market-managed-error-code

Comment: We don't really need to guess since in your code it's evident that code 3 is "ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error code 6 means that your app does not have the `com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE` permission. You need to declare in your manifest that your app uses this permission.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are getting

```
Activity My_company.My_appname.LicenseVerification has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker@41da7698 that was originally bound here
```

Is telling you that you are leaking a a `ServiceConnection`.

To fix this, you have to call `onDestroy` on your `LicenceChecker` like this

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mChecker.onDestroy();
}
```

As stated in the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html):

> Failing to call the LicenseChecker's onDestroy() method can lead to
>   problems over the lifecycle of your application. For example, if the
>   user changes screen orientation while a license check is active, the
>   application Context is destroyed. If your application does not
>   properly close the LicenseChecker's IPC connection, your application
>   will crash when the response is received. Similarly, if the user exits
>   your application while a license check is in progress, your
>   application will crash when the response is received, unless it has
>   properly called the LicenseChecker's onDestroy() method to disconnect
>   from the service.

As of the ErrorCode 6 that you are experiencing, you will need to add the permission for license checking to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped removing the Javastack. Obviously my question is asking for 2 things. ErrorCode 6 and the Javatsack, which are independent. Immibis helped me out, because I forgot to set a permission to get rid of the errorcode 6. Now I don't know to whom I should accept:-)

Comment: @user1344545 I'm glad to help. I added the `uses-permission` to my answer. The acceptance is solely up to you my friend.

Comment: The downvoter may kindly explain himself, since obviously my answer worked.

Comment: Dear Marcus. I upvoted your answer and accepted immibis ones. But now its "0". When I vote up again its "-1". I upvoted again. So there is someone else that downvoted ? Sorry for this situation. All the best..